# Node.js passing variable to client via express render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using Node.js express server I want to pass a variale to index.ejs file in client side, so I have this in server:

```
res.render("dashboard/index", { hidePayment: true });
```

the issue is I cannt get the `hidePayment` variable in a script tag inside `index.ejs`:

I tried theses with no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var hidePayment = hidePayment;  // not working
      var hidePayment = "{{hidePayment}}";  // not working

      console.log('hidePayment', hidePayment)
</script>
```

How can we get the variable in a script tag?

Comment: in ejs its <%= %> read the docs https://ejs.co/ it would be `var hidePayment = <%= hidePayment %>;`

Comment: It really depends on your templating engine :)

Answer (score 0):

be careful when passing variables to client, they are basically transformed in to strings

```
var hidePayment = '<%= hidePayment %>' === 'true'
```